# Errai Framework code-size and performance (Errai-Tutorial)

Tags: performance, gwt, errai, code-size

I am thinking of using Errai for a new project.  I like all the levels of abstraction that it uses and the concise and declarative code that can be written.

My main concerns are the taxes I need to pay to implement this framework, related to js code size and performance.

Some specific questions are:

1. For an equivalent app in GWT using RPC or RF, what was the difference in performance and js code size that people have experienced.
2. I implemented the Errai.Tutorial 3.1.1 and ran ‘clean package wildfly:deploy’.  This gets me 18 permutations of about **1.01 MB** each. This seems to be minified and obfuscated already.  Is this the expected size?

1MB of Javascript seems to be a lot for a bare bone app with only a couple of classes and limited functionality.

I do see the following in the text, which makes me think that the code is needlessly bloated:

```
[INFO] WARN [EnvUtil] reachability analysis disabled. errai may generate unnecessary code.
[INFO] WARN [EnvUtil] enable reachability analysis with -Derrai.compile.perf.perform_reachability_analysis=true
```

But when I make the change to the POM in the '***exraJvmArgs***' tag, I get the following error:

```
cannot resolve injectable bean for type: org.jboss.errai.jpa.client.local.ErraiEntityManager;
```

Thanks,
Steve